# VBS Application with Webbrowser control and Javascript

Tags: javascript, vbscript, webbrowser-control

I have a VBS application with a webbrowser control. In this control I open an HTML file which contains JavaScript. This JavaScript just sets a variable to value, like this:

```
var clicked = 3;
```

Do I have any possibilty to use this variable in my VBS application? Can I return the value?

Thank you!

---

in my Webbrowswer control I use the event DocumentComplete?
And in this event I say:

```
Dim oScript As Object
set myVariables = oScript.clicked
```

?
If I have more than one global variable, how can I chose the right one?
And If I set this variable in javascript in an OnClick event the event "DocumentComplete" is not the right one, or?
And the line `Dim oScript As Object` is not accepted in Viszal Basic Script?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by VBS application? I am guessing it could be (1) HTA Application, (2) Web App (i.e. web page), (3) ASP, (4) CScript/WScript or (5) ScriptHost application.

Comment: It is a Visual Basic Script 6.0 Application. And there I've got a form with a Webbrowser Control. So I think it is WScript.

Comment: Okay, I understand. You have a Visual Basic application (not VBScript; your question is misleading and mistagged). Your wish to share content between your javascript and your Visual Basic application.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer may not be applicable to Visual Basic 6.0, but, in VB .NET and C# you do something like this: WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("eval", "clicked"). Perhaps you can find something similar in Visual Basic 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

VB6 is good at late binding, so you do not need to deal with automation stuff like IDispatch and DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET. Just Dim oScript As Object and set it to webbrowser.document.script in the DocumentComplete event. DocumentComplete is also a good place to replace element handlers, see [handle html element events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb508508%28VS.85%29.aspx), in case you want to sink element events, then you can call oScript.clicked to get the global variable's value. That is, unless you [turn on the IE9 mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation) in your webbrowser control, then you need to deal with IDispatchEx and COM madness.

[Read Javascript variable from Web Browser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876555/read-javascript-variable-from-web-browser-control) is the C# version of this question.

Comment: My question was just an example. In my Javascript I set this variable "clicked" in an OnClick-Event.
So the Webbrowser Event "DocumentFinished" is not the right one, or?
And in Visual Basic Script I think there is no solution  to say "Dim oScript As Object" I think you have to create an object. Can you please explain a little bit more?
In my Webbrowser Event I just say "oScript.clicked"?? And this .clicked is my variable in Javascript?

Comment: If you set the variable later, then you need to check its value later, document complete is before the user click. And I was assuming you having a VB app, how did you write an ActiveX host in VBS?