# Is it possible to detect any javascript functions are called when using C# WebBrowser

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms, browser

Is it possible I can detect javascript functions are called when using C# WinForms WebBrowser ? I know it is easy to do it if the javascript functions are my own.  But as today I need to browse others' pages, for example, can it be detected when .createElement() or .appendChild() is called?

Comment: What is _C# WebBrowser_?

Comment: The component of C#. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Willy, you am everything right.

Comment: Check out this answer to [Read Javascript variable from Web Browser control](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6879120/205233) - it should give you a starting point.

Comment: So you really meant the [WinForms WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx), right?

Comment: Yeah, that is what I use. I edited my question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try to inject some Javascript into the control by appending code to the head, similar to this post: [How to Inject Javascript in Web Browser Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/how-to-inject-javascript-in-webbrowser-control).  The injected code could be a function to monitor events on a particular DOM element.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think I have to override the native functions which I want to detect if I do this way. But I still wonder if WebBrowser can provide me more information as it is the one which executes the javascript functions.

Comment: You might have the injected Javascript code call back to C# methos to provide the higher level object in your code.  This article describes how to do that: http://notions.okuda.ca/2009/06/11/calling-javascript-in-a-webbrowser-control-from-c/