# access global javascript variable in c# webbrowser

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms, browser

I have a Javascript file that has a global variable which is set to some integer value. I load the Javascript in C# using a WebBrowser control. 
I need to display the value of the global variable in a WinForms Label.

I have tried putting the global variable in a hidden html field and calling the following C# code:

```
var distance = mapWebBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")["distance"];

        if (distance != null)
            mileageText.Text = Convert.ToString(distance);
```

But this displays the `System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement` in the label whereas I need the actual value stored inside it.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Have you tried `mileageText.Text = distance.InnerText` ?

Comment: That doesn't seem to display anything.

Comment: Did you try `element.value`?

Comment: HtmlElement doesn't have a .value member.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read Javascript variable from Web Browser control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876555/read-javascript-variable-from-web-browser-control)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does giving the hidden field an id and calling this work? `mapWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("distance").InnerHtml` (where distance is the id)

Comment: No, that wouldn't work as hidden fields don't have InnerHtml - apologies. How about this? `mapWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("distance").GetAttribute("value")`

Comment: This gives me an error:
    `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Could you post the HTML of the hidden field that you're storing the value in? The id might be different, especially if it's been generated from the server side.

Comment: HTML: `<input type="hidden" id="distance" ></input>` JavaScript:
`document.getElementById('distance').value = distance;`

Comment: It may not make a difference but could you make the input self-closing? Also, could the server-side code be trying to access the value before the javascript has written it to the hidden field?

Comment: i think that might be what is happening. I will try using an element where I can set the inner html and use the .InnerHtml method you suggested. Thanks levelnis.