# C# - replacement of WebClient.downloadString in webbrowser control

Tags: c#, vsto, webbrowser-control, webclient

I am new to webbrowser control, I need to download string from server via **Rest API** in web browser control of my window application.

Is there any replacement of **webClientObject.DownloadString()** method in webbrowser control.

Comment: Do you mean you just want to get the HTML source of the page you're currently viewing in the WebBrowser?

Comment: No, I want to call a Rest API from my webbrowser and catch the response

Comment: That doesn't really make sense, why would you use a `WebBrowser` for that? It's not what it's meant for at all. Why can't you use `WebClient`?

Comment: @RamaKrishna - Why Stick to WebBrowserControl? Why cant you use HttpWebRequest? With WebBrowserControl you can only call GET Apis. To do that just navigate to the GET Api --- like: http://server:port/rest/ApiName. This will do GET call to the Url.

Comment: I am using WebBrowser for login user via SSO, after completion of successful login I need to capture user authentication details like sessionID .etc.

Comment: @Prateek Shrivastava Yes you are right, but my API is response is string how can I capture that string into variable?

Answer (score 1):

Try call Navigate method

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(address));
```

then call WebBrowser.OnNavigated Method.

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender,
    WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    // get webBrowser1.DocumentText Property or webBrowser1. DocumentStream
```

You can try [WebBrowser.InvokeScript this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876555/read-javascript-variable-from-web-browser-control)  to get javascript variable or ịnject javascript to get Rest APi url, or Rest API content

Comment: You can only Call GET  restful api using this method. What about PUT/DELETE etc?

Comment: Yes it is working fine, but my url results a string I need to capture that. How can I catch that string into variable?

Comment: If the above works - that means your api is GET only. Once the Navigated event is hit (like in example above) read the control.DocumentText

Comment: Above approach is working but asking to save downloaded content as a json file.

Comment: I don't want to download as a file, I want to capture that info as a string variable

Comment: @ Prateek Shrivastava control.DocumentText doesn't contains my api response